# xcode iphone project and ipad project into universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

If I have a project that was written for iphone and a project written for ipad. Is there a recommended way to combine them into a universal app?

My understanding is that you would take the existing app (iphone project) and convert it to a universal app then rename the classes to class_iphone, class_ipad etc.

The process of coverting includes xcode generating a new MainWindow nib for the ipad and other related files...  But this sound painful to go into the project and duplicate the files etc..

please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to rename your NIBs to be iPhone and iPad specific, but you shouldn't have to do that with your classes. I am not saying that it won't be painful - just that it will be a different kind of pain. You will need to wrap certain code in:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
    }
else
    {
    }
```

And you will need to be careful about classes (like UIPopoverController) that are specific to iPads.

Comment: How about using a different xcdatamodel? Is it possible for the iphone to use a different xcdatamodel then the ipad?  The ipad has a few more entities and I dont want to write the migration or combine the datamodel

Comment: If I dont use any nib or interface builder couldnt i just modify the main.h and use your if statement (above) to launch the correct appDelegate?

Comment: I would think so. And have, as you described in your original posting, essentially two complete and distinct application code bases in a single executable? It sounds like a doable first step. I haven't done this. I have only generalized a working iPhone app to be a universal iOS app.